Void Typecasting - Middle of Structure
I'm attempting to write a program that takes data from main (member type structure), then passes it to (void *) within the function, placing it on the stack in a linked list.  In order to use this code for future things, I'm trying to make it as generic as possible, which is why the functions use void within them, not the structure (member).  As a test, I'm passing 5 into member.test, then I'm trying to print the value of f_llist.head->info->test by typecasting to (struct member) in order to confirm 5 was placed in head..  For some reason, I'm struggling to get the syntax to work with this typecast; it's probably something very minor, but I can't seem to find it.  My code is below:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _person
{
int test;
}person;

typedef struct _node
{
void * info;
struct _node * next;
}node;

typedef struct _llist
{
struct _node * head;
struct _node * tail;
}llist;

void pushhead(llist * ff_list, void * info)
{
node * new_node=NULL;
new_node=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
(new_node->info)=info;  //Trying to get this node to point to generic data type
new_node->next=ff_list->head;
ff_list->head=new_node;
}

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
llist f_llist;
person member;
member.test=5;
pushhead(&f_llist, &member);
printf("%d", (f_llist.head->(struct _person *)info)->test);  //Can't figure out syntax to do this
}


Have you tried breaking it down into multiple lines? void* my_info = f_llist.head->info; person* p_person = (person*) my_info; int val = p_person->test;

If it works, then maybe try ((person*) f_llist.head->info)->test

That worked, thank you!
